# TypeError: Cannot read property 'turboThreshold' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

Using bar chart with drill down feature of **Highchart JS**. Bar chart gets updated dynamically based on button click. When particular bar is clicked to see next level data after that button is clicked to update data of graph at this moment it throws

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'turboThreshold' of undefined. im using drill down feature with react-jsx-highchart.

Sample code to reproduce the issue https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-4ippjp?file=DrillChart.js

step to reproduce:

1. click any category and drill down
2. click Update Chart button

Versions:

```
React JSX Highcharts version: ^3.4.0
Highcharts version: ^7.0.0 
React version: ^16.5.2
```

Comment: Hi @Devika B, I recommend you to use `highcharts-react-official` (https://www.npmjs.com/package/highcharts-react-official) wrapper, which is officially supported by Highcharts.

Comment: @ppotaczek , Thank you for your recommendation. Since I used React JSX Highcharts, wanted to solve this issue using that wrapper itself.